# Form which creates a quantity of another model with form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms, rails-models

I have two models, `Hotel` and `Room`. I want to create a form that will allow me to add a new hotel and rooms, which indicates the name of the hotel and the quantity of rooms.
I know I should use "nested form", but it is hard for me to implement it properly.

Here is my code:

HotelsController

```
class HotelsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @hotels = Hotel.all
  end

  def new
    @hotel = Hotel.new
  end

  def create
    @hotel = Hotel.new(hotel_params)

    if @hotel.save
      redirect_to @hotel
    else
      render 'new'
    end           
  end

  def show
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])
    @hotel.destroy
    redirect_to hotels_url, notice: 'Hotel was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  private

  def hotel_params
    params.require(:hotel).permit(:name, :rooms_count)
  end
end
```

Hotel model

```
class Hotel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rooms, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rooms
end
```

Room model

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :hotel, optional: true # avoiding rails 5.2 belongs_to error 
end
```

form

```
<%= form_with scope: :hotel, url: hotels_path, local: true do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :name %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :rooms_count %><br>
    <%= form.number_field :rooms_count %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <% form.fields_for :rooms  do |f|%>
      <p>
        **THE CODE**
      </p>
    <% end %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my question.

```
  def create
    @hotel = Hotel.new(hotel_params)
    @hotel.rooms_count.times do 
      @hotel.rooms.build
    end

    if @hotel.save
      redirect_to @hotel
    else
      render 'new'
    end           
  end
```

It implement a @hotel.rooms.build as many times as @hotel.rooms_count number entered in Rooms Count field in form.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the "ERB echo sign" (`=`) on the `fields_for` helper.

Correct form:

```
  <%= form.fields_for :rooms do |f|%>
```